# Getting null value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have a default JSON file :-

```
{
    "_name":"__tableframe__top",
    "_use-attribute-sets":"common.border__top",
    "__prefix":"xsl"
}
```

I am trying to push some value by creating an array , but I am getting my array **undefined** value after pushing the data

```
{
    "_name":"__tableframe__top",
    "_use-attribute-sets":"common.border__top",
    "__prefix":"xsl",
    "attribute":[undefined]
}
```

First I am checking if the object contains array or if not then create the array. And if if already an array is there then do nothing.

```
    if(!($scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute instanceof Array)){
        const tableframe__top_content = $scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute;
        $scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute = [tableframe__top_content];
 }
```

After this , I am checking if attribute with `_name` = `something` is already there or not in the array. If not then push.

```
var checkTableFrameTopColor = obj => obj._name === 'border-before-color';
        var checkTableFrameTopWidth = obj => obj._name === 'border-before-width';

        var checkTableFrameTopColor_available = $scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute.some(checkTableFrameTopColor);

        var checkTableFrameTopWidth_available = $scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute.some(checkTableFrameTopWidth);

        if( checkTableFrameTopColor_available === false && checkTableFrameTopWidth_available  === false ){
            $scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute.push({
                    "_name": "border-before-color",
                    "__prefix": "xsl",
                    "__text": "black"
                    },{
                    "_name": "border-before-width",
                    "__prefix": "xsl",
                    "__text": "1pt"
                     }
                     );
            console.log("pushed successfully");     
            console.log($scope.tObj);       
        }
```

I am getting null value on array and an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_name' of undefined at checkTableFrameTopColor`.

Where am I going wrong ?

**EDIT:-**

Like this I want to achieve-

```
{
    "attribute":[
                    {"_name":"font-weight","__prefix":"xsl","__text":"bold"},
                    {"_name":"color","__prefix":"xsl","__text":"black"}
                ],
    "_name":"__tableframe__top",
    "_use-attribute-sets":"common.border__top",
    "__prefix":"xsl"
}
```

Comment: some one told me to use square brackets just now may help? [my question just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514659/use-html-onclick-submit-button-to-search-js-array-and-then-display-specific-dat)

Comment: go to the developer tools of your browser and check the value of obj

Comment: Try creating a JSFiddle with your code and post the link here

Comment: @zip No , in the above code if  `"attribute": { }`is an object and  is present in the main  json object then it will turn to array. But there `attribute` is not present from begining

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul I have already mentioned in the question. Getting `{ "_name":"__tableframe__top", "_use-attribute-sets":"common.border__top", "__prefix":"xsl", "attribute":[undefined] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to guess but let me post it as an answer so I can use formatting…

Given:

```
const input = {
    "_name":"__tableframe__top",
    "_use-attribute-sets":"common.border__top",
    "__prefix":"xsl"
}
```

Note: Value of input.attribute is undefined.

```
    if(!($scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute instanceof Array)){
        const tableframe__top_content = $scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute;
        $scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute = [tableframe__top_content];
 }
```

.. so if this input is what you access in your if statement

```
input.attribute instanceof Array => false
```

it will be true and your code block will be executed and it says:

```
const example.attribute = [input.attribute]
// example.attribute == [undefined]
```

If I understand you correctly, you could solve it like so:

```
$scope.tObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute = (!tableframe__top_content) 
    ? [] 
    : [tableframe__top_content];
```

If attribute value could be false, you'd have to check with tableframe__top_content === undefined || tableframe__top_content === null.

Comment: Your logic is correct. Even I thought so but it is showing the same error. You mean like this  `if(!($scope.tableObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute instanceof Array => false))` ?

Comment: I updated the answer and added a suggested solution (before I just described why you see this error).

Comment: Ok , Yes I got it. Thanks for the solution. It  works .